# How can I set an Excel Pivot Table to show just Rank 1 via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table, rank

I have a list of Objects and I want to see the most used object. I know I could write a formula for this, if there was only 1 object which had the most use, but sometimes the results are tied and we can have 2, 3, 4... objects all used the same amount of times.

Therefore I believe a Pivot, using Ranking, could be the best way to present the results - as long as I can filter on all Objects with RANK 1.

However, I can't seem to work out how to get the Pivot to just display RANK 1 results.
For example, below is the data source;

```
Object
Pencil
Pencil
Pencil
Paper
Paper
Paper
Ruler
Ruler
Rubber
```

When put into a Pivot you would get:

```
Object  Vol.  Rank
Pencil  3     1
Paper   3     1
Ruler   2     2
Rubber  1     3
```

How do I get the Pivot to only display RANK 1.
And how would I write this in Excel VBA?

Comment: Have you tried `RANK` formula? See [here](https://www.contextures.com/excel-functions-rank.html). After that, just filter on Rank = 1 i guess.

Comment: You can apply Filter on Rank 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a filter "Top 1 Count" to the PivotField like this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    .PivotFields("Object").PivotFilters.Add2 _
        Type:=xlTopCount, _
        Value1:=1, _
        DataField:=.DataFields(1)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you.  I hadn't thought about the Top x Count option.  That works perfectly for what I need.